# Can anyone ID this leathery-leaf vine?

Tags: identification, vines

This vine is growing on a tree in PA in the wild. It is very old with thick vines near the ground and appears to be some kind of azalea, laurel or rhododendron. [image]

Comment: Looks like Euonymus. If it didn't vine, then Camelia.

Comment: That's clearly in a hanging pot inside a house, not growing on a tree. Wrong picture?

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the *Camellia* species/varieties, not sure which; it's not a vine, its a free standing shrub or small tree. 'Vine' refers to plants which climb or twine on a support or surrounding planting.

Comment: Ok folks it's growing outside 50 ft up a tree. I took a cutting and brought it inside. It's clearly a vine.

Comment: Can you add a photo of it growing in situ please, and how is it 'vining', is it scrambling, twining or attaching itself in some other way?